# How to get Cardano unspent transaction outputs (UTxO) via API?

Tags: python, blockchain, cryptocurrency, cardano

Currently, I can get only Cardano (ADA) "balance" via blockchain API but it does not include UTXOs.
I want to find the way how to get UTXO of Cardano address.

I use Python to get API.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup cardano rosetta server and fetch account coins and balance details from here:

```
https://www.rosetta-api.org/docs/AccountApi.html
```

and then you can create the utxo formats from here:

```
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-rosetta/blob/master/examples/commons.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python module for Cardano, the Wallet object has a [utxo_stats()](https://cardano-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) method which returns a histogram of UTxO statistics. The result consists of three elements: *total balance*, *histogram* and *scale*.

```
wallet.utxo_stats()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the BlockFrost API was able to do this with minimal effort.

I was using the .Net API but they have API for python.  Seems to be the best service I have found so far.

https://docs.blockfrost.io/